# How user threads are really scheduled? How is the OS (kernel) involved in such scheduling?

Tags: multithreading, cpu, scheduling

I’m reading the popular Operating System Concepts book but I can’t get how the user threads are really scheduled. There’s particularly a statement that confuses me :

“*User-level threads are managed by a thread library, and the kernel is unaware of them*”.

Let’s say I create the process A and 3 threads with the Pthreads library. My assumption is that user threads **must be necessarily** scheduled by the kernel (OS). Isn’t the OS responsible for allocating CPU? Doesn’t threads have their own registers and stack? So there must be a context switch ( registers switch ) and therefore there also must be some handling by the OS. **How can the kernel be unaware of them?**
How are user threads exactly scheduled?

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest implementation of user-level threads (a.k.a., "green threads"), there would be a function named `yield()`. The `yield()` function *is* the scheduler. When one thread calls it, it would;

- Choose which thread should run next according to the *scheduling policy.* If it happens to choose the calling thread, it would then simply return. Otherwise, it would...
- ...Save whatever registers any called function in the high-level language is obliged to save in the *saved context area* for the calling thread. This would include, at a minimum, the stack pointer. It probably also would include a frame pointer, and maybe a few general purpose registers.
- ...Restore the registers from the saved context area for the chosen thread. This would include the stack pointer, and since we're changing the stack pointer in mid-stream, so to speak, we'll have to be very careful about where the scheduler's own variables are kept. It won't really work for it to have "local" variables in the usual sense. There's a good chance that at least part of this "context switch" code will have to be written in assembly language,
- Finally, all it has to do is a normal function return, and it will be returning from a `yield()` call in the chosen thread instead of the original thread.

The function to create a new thread would;

- Allocate a block of memory for the thread's stack,
- Construct an *artificial* stack frame in the new stack that looks like the following function just called `yield()` from the line marked "// 1";

```c
void root_function(void (*thread_function)(void* args)) {
    yield();                 // 1
    thread_function(args);
    mark_my_own_saved_context_as_dead();
    yield();                 // 2
}
```

When the `thread_function()` returns, the thread will call the `mark_my_own_saved_context_as_dead()` function to notify the scheduler algorithm that the thread is dead. When the thread called `yield()` for the last time ("// 2"), then the scheduler algorithm would free up its stack, and clean up whatever else needs to be cleaned up before selecting some other thread to run.

---

In a typical implementation of green threads, there will be many other places where one thread *implicitly* yields to another. Any blocking I/O call, for example, or a `sleep()`, or any call to acquire a mutex or a semaphore.